# `__FILE__` not working within `DATA`/`__END__`

Tags: ruby

I'm working on [Practicing Ruby's Self-Guided Course on Stream, File Formats, and Sockets](https://practicingruby.com/articles/study-guide-1), and came across the following problem in the [pre-built test for the first exercise](https://github.com/elm-city-craftworks/course-001/blob/master/samples/part1/ls_tests.rb). The following test script is supposed to change the directory to the `data` subdirectory of the project folder:

```
eval(DATA.read) # load the test helper script
...             # various calls to test method defined below
__END__

dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
Dir.chdir("#{dir}/data")
...
```

But this breaks because `__FILE__` returns `(eval)` (instead of the path to the file) and `File.dirname(__FILE__)` returns `.` Why is this happening, and how should it be written to yield the intended output instead?

Comment: Hope my question is clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__END__` and `DATA` aren't really relevant here. You're simply passing a string to [`Kernel#eval`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval). For example, a simple `eval('__FILE__')` also returns `"(eval)"` because that's the default *filename*. It can be changed by passing another string but as third argument:

```
eval('__FILE__', nil, 'hello.rb')  # => "hello.rb"
```

Or in your case:

```
eval(DATA.read, nil, __FILE__)
```

Comment: Very insightful! Thanks.